# How to Submit a SOAP Message to External Web service URL?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, soap-client

I am trying to send a SOAP Message to a external Url.
My Code is as a below.

```
namespace SeadSOAPMessage
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CallWebService();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }


        public static void CallWebService()
        {
            var _url = "http://www.webservicex.com/globalweather.asmx";
            var _action = "http://www.webservicex.com/globalweather.asmx?op=GetWeather";


            XmlDocument soapEnvelopeXml = CreateSoapEnvelope();
            HttpWebRequest webRequest = CreateWebRequest(_url, _action);
            InsertSoapEnvelopeIntoWebRequest(soapEnvelopeXml, webRequest);

            // begin async call to web request.
            IAsyncResult asyncResult = webRequest.BeginGetResponse(null, null);

            // suspend this thread until call is complete. You might want to
            // do something usefull here like update your UI.
            asyncResult.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();

            // get the response from the completed web request.
            string soapResult;
            using (WebResponse webResponse = webRequest.EndGetResponse(asyncResult))
            {
                using (StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    soapResult = rd.ReadToEnd();
                }
                Console.Write(soapResult);
            }
        }

        private static HttpWebRequest CreateWebRequest(string url, string action)
        {
            HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            webRequest.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", action);
            webRequest.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"";
            webRequest.Accept = "text/xml";
            webRequest.Method = "POST";
            return webRequest;
        }

        private static XmlDocument CreateSoapEnvelope()
        {
            XmlDocument soapEnvelop = new XmlDocument();
            soapEnvelop.LoadXml(@"<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"" xmlns:soap=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/""><soap:Body><GetWeather xmlns=""http://www.webserviceX.NET""><CityName>string</CityName><CountryName>string</CountryName></GetWeather></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>");
            return soapEnvelop;
        }

        private static void InsertSoapEnvelopeIntoWebRequest(XmlDocument soapEnvelopeXml, HttpWebRequest webRequest)
        {
            using (Stream stream = webRequest.GetRequestStream())
            {
                soapEnvelopeXml.Save(stream);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The WSDLs  am using are.
[wsdl url](http://www.webservicex.com/globalweather.asmx)

[method Url](http://www.webservicex.com/globalweather.asmx?op=GetWeather)
After doing all the Proceess here I am getting the exception as

```
The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.
```

and after that if i'll Continue execution then second time I am getting another exceptioni.e

```
EndGetResponse can only be called once for each asynchronous operation.
```

so,what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Try tracing the request in a proxy like e.g. fiddler and see if there is any extra information in the response.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the issue by passing a correct url int the _action variable i.e

```
 var _action = "http://www.webservicex.com/globalweather.asmx/GetWeather";
```

and  was passing the wrong one i.e

```
var _action = "http://www.webservicex.com/globalweather.asmx?op=GetWeather";
```